# iframe data on webpage inside of a UIwebView my domain won't load others will

Tags: ios, html, iframe, uiwebview

So I published my app and I wish to upgrade it.  My app is entirely local HTML5 inside a UIwebView.  My webpages show images from local storage and from 3rd party domains and from my own domain.  Works great.  I also load 3rd party webpages using iframe  works great.  When I attempt to load a webpage from my own domain the page will not load in an iframe.  Why not?  It does not matter if I point to the DNS or IP of the page.  Same thing, will not load.

Comment: please put it in code by using backticks: \`code here\`

Comment: I really don't know how to be more specific than that.  I can use an iframe to load data in my app from anywhere except from my own server. I can load images from any server including my own.

Comment: for a start - what is your site? what is the specific section your trying to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed my own web server I named it earthHappens.com.  The configuration before this break was my domain was pointing to a host with an alias at Network Solutions 02da1a1.netsolhost.com.  Now it is pointing to an IP.  The failure began when earthHappens.com was pointing to earthHappens.com.  I deleted this host name from my server and it now works like before.

Thanks for your help Alex,  This caught me so off guard that I had a hard time slowing down my thoughts to realize what I had done to break it and my published app was broken so I was a little freaked:)  send me an e-mail and I'll send you a promo-code.  (iPhone) -Brad